# SendBird Laravel API with React Front End

Tags: laravel, sendbird

I have a `Laravel` back end serving `APIs` to a `React` front end for a solution I am developing. I want to integrate `SendBird Chat API` into the application to allow authenticated users to chat with each other.

My query is, how can I pass authenticated user details to SendGrid? I.e., if user `X` and user `Y` both log into the website, how do I allow them to talk to each other?

I am pretty sure I've misunderstood something around sessions but any help is appreciated.

I am not looking for a specific code answer but a general architectural answer.

Answer (score -1):

You send request from your frontend app, Laravel API receives request, builds whole application (all of your code) to process it and returns response. That is one request lifecycle and `Auth::user()` is going to be the user which sent request.

[Request lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle) explains this in much more detail but I recommend first learning about the basics of Client <-> Server architecture